# Adding a dynacmic data value in every particular data

Tags: php, math

hello new php programmer here, im creating an cms evaluation and i want the value of that evaluation to auto add and divided to a portion percentage ex.(35%) for that evaluation please kindly guide me how the logic.

```
Add all points with the eva 1 id compute the percentage base on given percent data
currently out put 
code :
<?php echo $roweva["evaluation"];?>(<?php echo $roweva["percent"];?>%)
<?php echo $rowpts["points"]; ?> hidden-><?php echo $roweva["maxpts"]; ?>
view :
eva 1 (50%)
5
5
5
eva 2 (50%)
10
10
```

what i want to get for the output is the addition of all points of that particular evaluation and its percent %, for clear explanation see the example input and ouput below.

```
ex .
input / get data:

eval 1 50%  --> 50%(if all q are max points)
ques1 5/10     -->/10(the maxpoints)
ques2 5/5      --> 3 ques 
ques3 5/5
eval 2 50%
ques1 10/10    --> 2 ques 
ques2 10/10

out put :
eval 1  = 15 points  37.5%  ---(20 max pts & 75% of 50%)
eval 2  = 20 points  50%    ---(20 max pts & 100% of 50%)
```

Comment: To know how many point you have use count()... ie:

    echo count($rowpts["points"]);

Now i dont know the structure of your "points" array so it's hard to tell the rest of the logic.

Comment: please put the output of: print_r($rowpts); in your question.

Comment: i update the quesion sir for currently view out put

Comment: ok but this doent help, just put the ouput of this:  print_r($rowpts);